# What would be the trajectory relative to the thrower of an object thrown upwards while the thrower is falling?

Tags: kinematics, reference-frames, projectile

So the thrower, or launcher is facing upwards, and is throwing say a liquid, upwards while it is accelerating downwards due to gravity. The thrower starts throwing when its speed is already 10m/s and it throws upwards at 1m/s (relative to itself, so 9m/s relative to the ground,towards the ground). Think of it as constantly shooting liquid, or shooting bullets in rapid succession. (No air resistance)

Comment: If the liquid is being projected in a vertical direction, it will follow a vertical path, provided the person "throwing" the liquid is moving vertically.

Answer (score 1):

The way to understand this is to imagine the thrower is floating weightless in outer space far from any gravitational fields. Then when the thrower throws an object at 1 m/s that object just moves in a straight line away from the thrower at 1 m/s so the trajectory is very simple.

The reason for starting this way is that if you are falling freely in a gravitational field it is almost the same as floating in space i.e. in both cases you are weightless. So if you are falling freely and you throw an object at 1 m/s it just moves away from you in a straight line just as it would in outer space. The trajectory will be more complicated as seen by an observer standing on the Earth, but for you it is very simple.

The reason I said *almost the same* above is that the Earth's gravitational field is not constant but instead varies with height. If you are falling freely and you throw a ball upwards then the gravitational field at the ball is slightly less than the gravitational field at your location. Conversely if you throw the ball downwards the gravitational field at the ball is slightly greater than the gravitational field at your location. This means whether you throw the ball upwards or downwards it will have a small acceleration away from you. This acceleration is know as a [tidal force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_force).